# Pushing UILabel with another UILabel

Tags: iphone

I am working on an app in which I need to have the ability to tap and drag UILabels around. The second challenge is that I need the other UILabels on the screen to move out of each others way (never overlap). So as I drag one label and run into another, it bumps the second out of the way. Perhaps an important note is that each label will be random rotations as well.

I am sorry but I don't really have any code to share because I am not sure where to start with collision detection of this sort.

Perhaps CGRectIntersectRect() ?

Comment: You should probably start by reading any introductory book to game mechanics, specifically about collision detection. After that, a good place to start implementing the collision detection code might be in `-layoutSubviews` of the container view. Just make sure the code that's repositioning the dragged around view properly calls `-setNeedsLayout` on the container or what have you.

Comment: I haven't used either of these yet, but one may help: http://box2d.org/forum/ and http://box2d.org/forum/ (but also may be overkill)

Comment: What I am creating is not a game. Does that make any difference or is a game/graphics framework the best bet?

Comment: It's not important if it's a game or not, really, but since collision detection is so important in games, all the good intro to game mechanics books and even blogs usually have really good chapters on doing collision detection. Also, since games are so popular in iOS, there are a lot of books which talk specifically about doing collision detection on iOS. My suggestion is to learn the basics of collision detection first, then apply it to your specific need.

Comment: If you aren't creating a game them you probably don't need a physics engine. But it would still be beneficial to read up on how games do collision detection as it is most commonly seen in games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn to use [Cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/), you can set layers for images for your overlapping problem. You can create your own labels and just set their position to accelerate towards where the user touched, or customize this however you want.

Also with the collision detection, this would be easy to implement in Cocos2d.

Comment: Why do people prefer Cocos2d over the OpenGL framework in the SDK? Easier?